# How does one set coefficients of the sawtooth wave using Fourier series?

Tags: fourier-series

The traditional sawtooth is written as

$\frac{A}{2}-\frac {A}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac {\sin (2\pi kft)}{k}$

The general formula is given as

\begin{equation}
s(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[a_n\cos\left(nx\right)+b_n\sin\left(nx\right)\right] \\
=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \sin(nx), \quad \mathrm{for} \quad x - \pi \notin 2 \pi \mathbf{Z}.
\end{equation}

What is the "rule" for the coefficients? This is $a_{0}$ for all odd coefficients and all b coefficients equal to zero?

Is there a resource you could recommend which explains this process?

Comment: [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeries.html) you can see the formulae in order to obtain the coefficients.